# Are Feynman diagrams analytic functions of the external momenta?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, regularization

I was reading Ashok Das's book on QFT and came across this statement:

> Thus we see explicitly that any Feynman amplitude can be Taylor expanded so that the divergent parts can be separated out as local functions (independent of momenta).

Unfortunately he never proved this statement nor did he give any references for it, but just verified it explicitly for two diagrams from the Yukawa theory; he showed that the fermion self energy and scalar self energy (at one loop) can be expanded as an analytic function of the external momenta. I have attached a picture of the two pages where he did the calculation (I tried to do the calculation myself but I just can't prove that the next term in the expansion in powers of $p$ is finite as $\Lambda$ goes to infinity)[image: The two pages where the fermion self energy and scalar self energy were explicitly expanded as a function of momenta]
 Is this statement about the analyticity of the Feynman diagrams as a function of the external momenta true in general?